# Alternatives to underscore.js

Tags: javascript, json, datatable, underscore.js, lodash

I am looking for a JavaScript library that manipulates arrays of objects, mainly for filtering, sorting and grouping/counts.

It seems that underscore.js fits the bill, but I'd be interested to explore other options. Underscore has 60+ functions while I just need a handful.

For example, I would expect some datatable libraries to include such features, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: you can always try just stripping out the *handful of functions/methods* you need form the [source](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html)

Comment: Based on Raynos' answer, I am actually thinking I should strip out what I need from the ES5 shim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called JavaScript `arr.filter` , `arr.sort` , `arr.length`.

You can apply any array method on an array, popular ones are `filter`, `map` and `reduce`, You can build more complex operations by combining those.

If you want to iterate over objects use

```
Object.keys(o).forEach(function (key) {
  var val = o[key];
  ...
});
```

underscore is useful if you live in an ES3 world, but ES5 has everything you need, all underscore does is add bloat on top of it.

Comment: `arr.length`? I doesn't that  give you the number of pirates in your program? ;)

Comment: I live in a world where IE 8 and even IE 7 are still popular... http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: Thx! Definitely an option I want to explore.

Comment: @Raynos what do you recommand to do if I need functions like array_diff/array_intersect? build some custom function or use a library?

Comment: @danip `require("interset/intersect")` `require("difflet")`. There are plenty of modules that do an individual task well. Find them, use them.

Comment: Lets not forget that all the so called "bloat" Underscore adds is very useful in a lot of cases. Like standard libraries in other languages it saves you time and furthermore it sorts browser differences that does exist unless you live in a world with only one browser.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is old but did you look at [lodash](http://lodash.com/)? From the site:

A drop-in replacement* for Underscore.js.
[...]

Custom builds make it easy to create lightweight versions of Lo-Dash containing only the methods you need. To top it off, we handle all method dependency and alias mapping for you.

Comment: What's the advantage of Lo-Dash over Underscore?  Underscore is already tiny.

Comment: @blaster: Lo-Dash is quite a bit more optimized. You can see some nice visualized benchmark results here: http://dtao.github.io/lazy.js/

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at lazy.js (http://dtao.github.io/lazy.js/) similar to underscore.js but with significant performance improvment due to lazy evaluation

Comment: This library only gains performance when you want to chain multiple operations together. Performing a single `map()` or `reduce()` will see zero performance gain (it will actually be slower in some cases especially compared to lodash). However, its performance gains are **really** noticeable when operating on very large data sets.

Comment: @idbehold: It depends on the environment and the size of the array, as different JavaScript engines behave very differently. On Chrome, for example, even for small arrays and without chaining Lazy.js outperforms Lo-Dash. But on Firefox, you're right that Lo-Dash is faster in that scenario.

Answer (score 7):

A couple more here

- https://github.com/ded/valentine
- http://sugarjs.com/

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look into the following two libraries:

- [wu.js](http://fitzgen.github.com/wu.js/)
- [functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the second one only works on arrays of numbers, while I need a solution for arrays of objects.

Answer (score 1):

[lowscore](https://github.com/featurist/lowscore) is intended to be a very lightweight underscore:

- you can `require` only the functions you need
- can reduce JS size by roughly 15k minified, or about 50k non-minified.